# $\sum \:_{i=0}^{n-1}\:\:i\:=\:\frac{n\left(n-1\right)}{2}$ proof by induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I tried solving this by referring to an example, and I'm pretty sure it's wrong.. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong if so.

Claim: $$\text{For  all } n \ge  1$$

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\:\:i\:=\:\frac{n\left(n-1\right)}{2}$$
(I couldn't figure out how to sigma notation without using integral so don't be be confused ha..)

Proof (By Induction)

**Base Case ($n = 1$)**:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\:\:i\:=\:\sum_{i=0}^0\:\:i\:=\:0 = 1(1-1)/2$$

**Inductive Hypothesis ($n = k$)**:

Assume: $$\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\:\:i\:=\:\frac{k\left(k-1\right)}{2}$$

**Induction Step ($n = k+1$)**:

To Show:$$\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\:\:i\:=\:\frac{k\left(k-1\right)}{2}$$

$$\frac{\left(k+1\right)\left(\left(k+1\right)-1\right)}{2}=\frac{\left(k+1\right)\left(k\right)}{2}$$

$$=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\:\:i\:=\:\sum_{i=0}^{k}\:\:i+\left(k+1\right)$$
(By Inductive Hypothesis):
$$=\frac{k\left(k-1\right)}{2}+\left(k+1\right)$$

$$=\frac{k\left(k-1\right)}{2}+\frac{2\left(k+1\right)}{2}$$

$$=\frac{\left(k-1\right)\left(k+2\right)}{2}$$

Comment: You need to add $+k$ to both sides, not $+(k+1)$

Comment: I correct ed and simplified the proof of the base case ... you previously used n=0 instead of n=1

Comment: Dear Temur, You are wrong in Inductive Hypothesis.

Comment: I corrected a typo in your Induction step (right before the Inductive Hypothesis) where you said $= +k+1$ which should have been just $+k+1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to be more careful exactly what you assume and what you need to show, i.e. how you organize the proof. Organization is half the battle for proofs!

OK, you assumed the k case, so you need to show the k+1 case, i.e. you need to show:

$$\sum \:_{i=0}^{(k+1)-1}\:\:i\:=\:\frac{(k+1)\left((k+1)-1\right)}{2}=\frac{\left(k+1\right)\left(k\right)}{2}$$

so you need to show:

$$\sum \:_{i=0}^{k}\:\:i\:=\:\frac{(k+1) k}{2}$$

Once you have established what you need to show, you start with the left side and (using the hypothesis at some point of course) try to get to the right side. So:

$$\sum \:_{i=0}^{k}\:\:i\:=\:\sum \:_{i=0}^{k-1}\:\:i \: + k\:=\: ...$$

(...and there is your mistake ... you added $k+1$ instead of $k$. So you really get:)

$$\sum \:_{i=0}^{k-1}\:\:i \: + k\:=\: $$ (Inductive Hypothesis)

$$\frac{k (k-1)}{2} + k\:=\: $$

$$\frac{k (k-1)}{2} + \frac{2k}{2}\:=\: $$

$$\frac{k (k-1) + 2k}{2}\:=\: $$

$$\frac{k^2 + k}{2}\:=\: $$

$$\frac{(k+1) k}{2}$$

Comment: when you're adding the "K" instead of K+1 is the k always a constant k added on that step? if you understand what I mean; like it's not changed from problem to problem

Comment: When you start on the left side of the equation you need to show, you have the sum of all numbers up to and including $k$, so that is the sum  of all numbers up to and including $k-1$ ... plus $k$ ... *not* plus $k+1$.

Comment: is the assumption not supposed to match the answer?

Comment: just wondering because I had the assumption (k(k-1)) / 2 

with a minus

Comment: Your assumption is just fine.  You just have the wrong set-up for the step. Again, it helps to first make clear exactly what you need to show. Since you assumed the formula_to_be_proven using $k$, you should show the formula_to_be_proven for $k+1$, and yet you start out with the $k$ case again.

Answer (score 0):

Base Case: $$\sum_{n=0}^{0}i=\frac{1(1-1)}{2}=0$$
Inductive Step: Assume $$\sum_{n=0}^{n-2}i=\frac{(n-1)(n-1-1)}{2}=\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}.$$ Adding $n-1$ to both sides, we have $$\sum_{n=0}^{n-2}i+(n-1)=\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}+(n-1)$$ $$\sum_{n=0}^{n-1}i=\frac{n^2-3n+2+2(n-1)}{2}=\frac{n^2-n}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}.$$ This concludes the proof.

Comment: A good proof ... but not what the OP asked for. He wanted to know what was wrong with his own proof.